# Insert or Update from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert several records from another table, and where there is a duplicate key, instead update the current record from the same table.

I've found several helpful answers on this site, but none seem to work for me. All return a syntax error, and I'm not sure if it's just the interface I'm using that doesn't support these commands or what. Inserting where there is no duplicate key, this query works fine. If there's any way anyone could should me what syntax could be used to properly execute these commands with the given I'd be incredibly grateful!

Here are the ones that seem to do exactly what I need, but haven't worked.

```
REPLACE INTO
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO
```

Here's a sample of what my INSERT query currently looks like:

---

```
USE database
GO
INSERT INTO products
(upc, name, price)
    select upc = TempTables.dbo.new_items.upc,
    name = TempTables.dbo.new_items.name,
    price = TempTables.dbo.new_items.price
FROM TempTables.dbo.new_items
```

Comment: Your question title and first paragraph make it sound as if it's a very basic question (much alike "How do I INSERT?"), while your question is perfectly fine and not newbish! Perhaps you can reword your question a bit so you don't scare away possible answerers.

Comment: Thank all of you so much for your responses! I vaguely remember trying to use a MERGE command after seeing it on here somewhere, but I must've had the syntax wrong. 

Seems I got it working this time!

Answer (score 3):

I personally like the `MERGE` statement

```
create table ##new_items (upc int, name int, price int)

create table ##products
(upc int, name int, price int)

merge into ##products [tgt]
using ##new_items [src]
on [tgt].upc = [src].upc and [tgt].name = [src].name 
when matched then update set price = [src].price 
when not matched then insert (upc, name, price) 
    values ([src].upc, [src].name, [src].price)
;
```

To see the items that you've working with, you might query like this

```
-- the items in new_items that aren't in products
select n.* from new_items n left outer join products p 
on n.upc = p.upc where p.upc is null

-- the items in new_items that are in products
select n.* from new_items n left outer join products p 
on n.upc = p.upc where p.upc is not null
```

Of course, once you run the update / insert / merge you won't know which items were already there and which have been inserted. If you wanted to know that you'd need to add an 'updated date' column to the table and mark it at that time.

Comment: The MERGE command worked great when I got the syntax right, thanks! As a follow up question, how could I run a SELECT of the items that were already in the table?

Comment: I've attempted to answer your question, does it make sense?

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I actually think I could run this select BEFORE the update and this could save me some trouble. To give some context, what I'm trying to do is insert new items, where they exist and have a price less than the price I'm updating, I want to select them and their current price so that I can run this update at a later time (not during store hours), but update any other columns. I've mostly got it now, just trying to get it to run in as few queries as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> What I need to do, is insert several records from another table, and where there is a duplicate key, instead update the current record from the same table.

That is usually done in two steps (some SQL servers have a syntax to do it in one step, but the more generic method is two steps)

```
(assuming the key is upc):

UPDATE products
SET name = new_items.name,
    price = new_items.price
FROM products
INNER JOIN new_items
   ON products.upc = new_items.upv 

INSERT INTO products
(upc, name, price)
SELECT 
    upc,
    name,
    price
FROM TempTables.dbo.new_items
WHERE upc NOT IN 
    (SELECT upc FROM products)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE products  
SET name = new_items.name, price = new_items.price
FROM products JOIN new_items USING(upc);

INSERT INTO products
(upc, name, price)
SELECT upc, name, price
FROM TempTables.dbo.new_items
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM products WHERE upc = TempTables.dbo.new_items.upc);
```

Considering, upc is your `Primary key`,

Here , `UPDATE` query will succeed if there is already a row with `upc in new_items`

`INSERT` query will succeed if row with `upc in new_items` does not exist.